# How to limit the number of dropdown items visible at a time on screen in AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` and want to limit the number of dropdown items visible at a time on the screen. Currently it fills up the screen but can I limit it to say 2 items with a scroll bar for displaying more.

Comment: You can limit number of items in your adapter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `setDropDownHeight(int height)` method of `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: yes but here you limit by pixels ,How can be limited by the number of items ?

Comment: Not sure if there is a function for this. But can you try by using View's getHeight() to get the height in pixels for 1 item, and then may be by using this can set the required height for n items.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.auto);

        String item[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "October", "November", "December"};


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this really what OP asked?